# Linq / Entity Framework not returning associated entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

On my `_LoginPartialCompanyAdmin` I have this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle count-info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                @if (User.IsInRole("Company Admin"))
                {
                    @Html.Action("GetModules", "Module")
                }
</a>
```

My module controller is like this:

```
public ActionResult GetModules()
{
    return PartialView(Cache.Module.GetModulesForUser(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Name));
}
```

And the cache method is like this:

```
public static List<Models.ModulosPorUsuario> GetModulesForUser(string identityname)
{
    /// It needs to be cached for every user because every user can have different modules enabled.
    var cachekeyname = "ApplicationModulesPerUser-" + identityname;

    IDatabase cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    List<Models.ModulosPorUsuario> listOfModulesPerUser = new List<Models.ModulosPorUsuario>();
    listOfModulesPerUser = (List<Models.ModulosPorUsuario>)cache.Get(cachekeyname);

    if (listOfModulesPerUser == null)
    {
        listOfModulesPerUser = dbApp.ModulosPorUsuario.Where(p => p.Email == identityname).ToList();
        cache.Set(cachekeyname, listOfModulesPerUser, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SettingsHelper.CacheModuleNames));
        return listOfModulesPerUser;
    }
    else
    {
        return listOfModulesPerUser;
    }
}
```

My seed initialization method is like this:

```
#region Seed Modules
var module1 = new Module() { Id = 1, ModuleName = "Contabilidad", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-ambulance" };
var module2 = new Module() { Id = 2, ModuleName = "Recursos Humanos", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-heartbeat" };
var module3 = new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Inventario", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-anchor" };
var module4 = new Module() { Id = 4, ModuleName = "Produccion", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-binoculars" };
var module5 = new Module() { Id = 5, ModuleName = "Produccion", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-binoculars" };
var module6 = new Module() { Id = 6, ModuleName = "Ventas", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-coffee" };
var module7 = new Module() { Id = 7, ModuleName = "Compras", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-calendar-o" };
var module8 = new Module() { Id = 8, ModuleName = "Cotizaciones", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-building" };

context.Modulos.Add(module1);
context.Modulos.Add(module2);
context.Modulos.Add(module3);
context.Modulos.Add(module4);
context.Modulos.Add(module5);
context.Modulos.Add(module6);
context.Modulos.Add(module7);
context.Modulos.Add(module8);
#endregion

#region Seed ModulosPor Usuario
context.ModulosPorUsuario.Add(new ModulosPorUsuario()
{
     Id = 1,
     Email = "companyadmin@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
     Modules = new List<Module>() { module1, module2 }
});

context.ModulosPorUsuario.Add(new ModulosPorUsuario()
{
    Id = 2,
    Email = "accountingadmin@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
    Modules = new List<Module>() { module3, module5 }
});

context.ModulosPorUsuario.Add(new ModulosPorUsuario()
{
    Id = 3,
    Email = "jayhamlin@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
    Modules = new List<Module>() { module4, module6 }
});

context.ModulosPorUsuario.Add(new ModulosPorUsuario()
{
    Id = 4,
    Email = "usuario1@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
    Modules = new List<Module>() { module7, module7 }
});

#endregion
```

However when debugging the `Cache` method, it's not returning any modules for the current user:

http://screencast.com/t/3UGd3NsR1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, the List<> had to be a virtual ICollection:

```
public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules{ get; set; }
```

Comment: `virtual List<>` might work also.. `virtual` is the important part